# Update Associated entity on updatign foreign key - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a mysql table which maintains data of drivers and maintains the city of the driver by using the foreign key mapping.

```
public class Drivers {

    private Integer currentCityId;

    private Integer id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



  @Column(name = "current_city_id")
    public Integer getCurrentCityId() {
        return currentCityId;
    }

    public void setCurrentCityId(Integer currentCityId) {
        this.currentCityId = currentCityId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinColumn(name = "current_city_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true, unique = false)
    public Cities getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setCities(Cities cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "cities", catalog = "mytable_production", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class Cities implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String aliasName1;
    private String aliasName2;
    private int stateId;

}
```

Now, I am updating the city of the driver by updating the foreignKey value in the table using

```
@Transactional 
public void updateCityBizLogic(int driverId,int newCityId) {

    //Some biz logic 
    Drivers d = driversDao.updateCity(driverId,newCityId);

    log.info("Updated driverCity to {}",d.getCities.getName());

}

public class DriversDao {
    @Transactional
    public Drivers updateCity(int DriverId, int newCityId) {

        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Drivers.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", Integer.parseInt(id)));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        Drivers d = criteria.list().get(0);

        d.setCurrentCityId(newCityId);
        session.update(d);
        return d;

    }
}
```

But in the log line, it is printing the old city name. I want the session to update the associated entities when I update any of the foreign key **( like update the joined cities object, when I update the cityId)**

Can someone point out what I am missing here and achieve it?

Comment: Have you declare id in Driver class, on which you are putting restriction. Which id you are expecting here?

Comment: @UmaShankarChaurasiya added the missing code part.